# Как сделать тени более светлыми?[unity]

Tags: unity3d

Не могу разобраться, как в юнити сделать более мягкие и менее темные тени на объектах. Я использую LWRP, но не уверен связано это с ним или нет.
Буду благодарен, если скажете в каком направлении искать решение.
Вот так модель выглядит у меня:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

**Windows/Rendering/Lighting Settings**

*Enviropment Lighting - Ambient Color*

Comment: У меня нет такой настройки(
https://ibb.co/qDrj7Pc

Comment: Поменяй Source с Skybox на Color